# MailApp/GmailApp fails to send bcc to address alias

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using GmailApp/MailApp to send notification emails, and I want to bcc my self using an "address alias", but no email is delivered to my gmail.

Example:

*Email is sent to **someone@somedomain.com** <- Works

BCC is sent to **mygmailacct+notifications@gmail.com** <- Does not work*

If I remove the "address alias" from my BCC, it works;
*BCC is sent to **mygmailacct@gmail.com** <- Works*

However this means I can't filter the notifications properly etc.

Sending an email to ***mygmailacct+notifications@gmail.com*** from some other email account works fine as expected.

Code:

```js
function sendEmail(to, subject, body) {
  
  // Default options
  var options = {
    name: 'System notifications',
    bcc: 'gmail.accnt+notification@gmail.com'
  };
  
  MailApp.sendEmail(to, subject, body, options);

}
```

Rule:

```
Matches: to:(mygmailacct+notifications@gmail.com)
Do this: Apply label "notifications", Never send it to Spam, Mark it as important
```

Comment: In Gmail, because of labels, essentially an email you send to yourself is there in the sent mail already. It doesn't need to come up in inbox as a separate copy. (though it should have the status of unread)

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks okay, It is probably skipping your inbox, try looking in **All Mail** or **Sent Mail**

> To prevent clutter, Gmail doesn't route messages that you send to your
>   own alias to your inbox. You can find the message in Sent Mail or All
>   Mail. If you need to see messages sent to your alias in the Inbox, you
>   can configure the alias as an alternate "Send mail as" address for
>   your account.
>   [— Source](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1703601?hl=en)

Comment: I've added the alias as an alternate address to my account, so now I get the email in my inbox, unread. However the filter looking for emails sent to the alias still doesn't trigger. So it's basically the same thing as sending the email to the "normal" address without the alias part...(the whole reason for the alias was filtering)

Comment: Exactly which of rules are not working?  I tried with labels and works just fine

Comment: I have a rule like so:

Comment: Can't seem to edit above comment, however I have a rule:  

to:(gmail.accnt+notification@gmail.com)  
Apply label "notification", Never send it to Spam, Mark it as important

This rule do not get applied, but sending an email to the alias from another account it does.