# MailApp fails to send message if to is omitted

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script

I'm getting

> Lo sentimos, se ha producido un error en el servidor. Espera un momento y vuelve a intentarlo. (línea n, archivo "Code")

Translation to English

> We're sorry, a server error was occurred. Wait a moment and try again. (line n, file "Code")

The line that throws the error is `MailApp.sendEmail(message);`

But when I look to Failed Executions on https://script.google.com and on Stackdriver there isn't logged any error.

Here is the MCVE:

```js
function sendEmail() {
  var subject = 'A nice subject';
  var plainText = 'Some text';
  var htmlBody = '<span style="color:blue;">Some text</span>';
  var message = {
    bcc: 'team@example.com',
    cc: 'myusername@example.com',
    subject: subject,
    body: plainText,
    htmlBody: htmlBody,
    noReply: true
  }
  MailApp.sendEmail(message);
}
```

What is wrong with the above code?

Similar question:

- [MailApp/GmailApp fails to send bcc to address alias](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40086944/1595451)

  - This question use `MailApp.sendEmail(to, subject, body, options);` instead of `MailApp.sendEmail(message);`. By the other hand the author of that question didn't include the values of `to`, `subject` and `body`. There is an answer but it doesn't help with my case as it suggest to look on mailbox but my issue is that the email isn't sent due to the cited error.

Comment: Added [tag:gs] to propose it as synonym of [tag:google-apps-script]. Related post in [meta] -> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/398818/1595451

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly why, but it looks that `to:` should be included, so I changed `cc:` to `to:` and it works  now.

```js
function sendEmail() {
  var subject = 'A nice subject';
  var plainText = 'Some text';
  var htmlBody = '<span style="color:blue;">Some text</span>';
  var message = {
    bcc: 'team@example.com',
    to: 'myusername@example.com',
    subject: subject,
    body: plainText,
    htmlBody: htmlBody,
    noReply: true
  }
  MailApp.sendEmail(message);
}
```